# Need assistance centralising an image in a list in my header?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I was just wondering how I would go about horizontally aligning all of the contents of the ul (unordered list) to the centre if that makes sense. As in instead of having their bottoms aligned, having their centres aligned.

Here is a photo of what it looks like currently: https://postimg.cc/S2YrpR24

Here is what I would like it to look like (Edited in photoshop): https://postimg.cc/N9YQT96G

My HTML for my header looks like this:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a>Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><img id="logo" src="img/schule logo light.png" alt="mainlogo"></li>
            <li><a>Our Resources</a></li>
            <li><a>The Teachers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

and my css looks like this:

```
header{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    color: #000000;
    padding-top: 10px;
    min-height: 110px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

header h1{
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 30px 0px 0px 0px;
    color: #000000;
}

header a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

header img{
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 40px;
}

header ul{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
}

header li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

This looks like a very good use for [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox), a decent [demo site](https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/):

```
HEADER UL {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-align-content: stretch;
  align-content: stretch
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an issue where the end on the right Is cut off as shown attached: https://postimg.cc/ftvDs44Z.

Comment: It seems that the parent container may be too wide then. Or that you have negative margins.

Comment: I dont think its either, I just need to centralise the whole list now.

Comment: You can play around with `justify-content:` try setting it to `space-around` or `center` and see if it's better.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe change

```
header img {
    padding-top: 0px;
}
```

to

```
header img {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

?

Hard to say with that snippets. Or post an URL?

Comment: That just moves all of the items in the list down for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example using flex and vertically aligned items:

```html
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a>Sign Up</a></li>
            <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" alt="test image"></li>
            <li><a>Our Resources</a></li>
            <li><a>The Teachers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<style>
    ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        align-items: center;
    }
    li {
        display: block;
        flex: 0 1 auto;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
</style>
```